# Wrong Alignment of Pictures

Tags: css, html, wordpress, css-float

Hello I have this problem with a photo that is positioned in the middle column. How may I fix this. Also I have to tell you that I'm using WordPress and I'm trying to build this in the Salient theme using "Nectar Shortcodes" also in the code below you have the link to my website, but you can`t visit it as it is under maintenance . Should I enter something in the Global CSS option box?

Here is a video to help you understand, here I'm using visual composer:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q1LixRT2LR0

```
  [heading subtitle="Proiectele noastre"] [/heading]
[one_third][image_with_animation animation="Fade In From Left" image_url="DELETED WEBSITE NAME" delay=""] [/image_with_animation] [/one_third]
[one_third][image_with_animation animation="Fade In From Bottom" image_url="DELETED WEBSITE NAME" delay=""] [/image_with_animation][/one_third]
[one_third_last][image_with_animation animation="Fade In From Right" image_url="DELETED WEBSITE NAME" delay=""] [/image_with_animation][/one_third_last]

[one_third][image_with_animation animation="Fade In From Left" image_url="DELETED WEBSITE NAME" delay=""] [/image_with_animation][/one_third]
[one_third][image_with_animation animation="Fade In From Bottom" image_url="DELETED WEBSITE NAME" delay=""] [/image_with_animation][/one_third]
[one_third_last][image_with_animation animation="Fade In From Right" image_url="DELETED WEBSITE NAME" delay=""] [/image_with_animation][/one_third_last]
```

[image]

**HTML PART**

```
 div id="fws_548dc4b895636" class="wpb_row vc_row-fluid standard_section   "  style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; "><div class="row-bg-wrap"> <div class="row-bg   " style=""></div> </div><div class="col span_12 dark ">
    <div  class="vc_span4 wpb_column column_container col no-extra-padding"  data-hover-bg="" data-animation="" data-delay="0">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div class="img-with-aniamtion-wrap left"><img class="img-with-animation " data-delay="0" data-animation="fade-in-from-left" src="DELETED WEBSITE URL" alt="" /></div>
        </div> 
    </div> 

    <div  class="vc_span4 wpb_column column_container col no-extra-padding"  data-hover-bg="" data-animation="" data-delay="0">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div class="img-with-aniamtion-wrap left"><img class="img-with-animation " data-delay="0" data-animation="fade-in-from-bottom" src="DELETED WEBSITE URL" alt="" /></div>
        </div> 
    </div> 

    <div  class="vc_span4 wpb_column column_container col no-extra-padding"  data-hover-bg="" data-animation="" data-delay="0">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div class="img-with-aniamtion-wrap left"><img class="img-with-animation " data-delay="0" data-animation="fade-in-from-right" src="http://DELETED WEBSITE URL/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/circus.png" alt="" /></div>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div></div>
    <div id="fws_548dc4b89602e" class="wpb_row vc_row-fluid standard_section   "  style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; "><div class="row-bg-wrap"> <div class="row-bg   " style=""></div> </div><div class="col span_12 dark ">
    <div  class="vc_span12 wpb_column column_container col no-extra-padding"  data-hover-bg="" data-animation="" data-delay="0">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">

        </div> 
    </div> 
</div></div>
    <div id="fws_548dc4b89650a" class="wpb_row vc_row-fluid standard_section   "  style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; "><div class="row-bg-wrap"> <div class="row-bg   " style=""></div> </div><div class="col span_12 dark ">
    <div  class="vc_span4 wpb_column column_container col no-extra-padding"  data-hover-bg="" data-animation="" data-delay="0">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div class="img-with-aniamtion-wrap left"><img class="img-with-animation " data-delay="0" data-animation="fade-in-from-left" src="hDELETED WEBSITE URL" alt="" /></div>
        </div> 
    </div> 

    <div  class="vc_span4 wpb_column column_container col no-extra-padding"  data-hover-bg="" data-animation="" data-delay="0">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div class="img-with-aniamtion-wrap left"><img class="img-with-animation " data-delay="0" data-animation="fade-in-from-bottom" src="http://www.DELETED WEBSITE URL/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/safe.png" alt="" /></div>
        </div> 
    </div> 

    <div  class="vc_span4 wpb_column column_container col no-extra-padding"  data-hover-bg="" data-animation="" data-delay="0">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div class="img-with-aniamtion-wrap left"><img class="img-with-animation " data-delay="0" data-animation="fade-in-from-right" src="DELETED WEBSITE URL" alt="" /></div>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div></div>
    <div id="fws_548dc4b896eeb" class="wpb_row vc_row-fluid standard_section   "  style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; "><div class="row-bg-wrap"> <div class="row-bg   " style=""></div> </div><div class="col span_12 dark ">
    <div  class="vc_span12 wpb_column column_container col no-extra-padding"  data-hover-bg="" data-animation="" data-delay="0">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" class="divider-border"></div>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div></div>
```

Comment: I did not down-voted, but I know that anonymous down-voters are the plague of SO. You did not provide enough information, no source code  (css, php) or information about what (and where) those images are generated (by some plug-in?). Without that it's like guessing from tea leaves.

Comment: Ok I will provide more details

Comment: It is a bit upsetting when they do this :) But i`ve got the message so it won`t happen again

Comment: Can you provide the generated html of the page that displays those six pictures?

Comment: Cant find it. If I were able to find it I would have fixed it....only the stylesheet and PHPs

Comment: "can't find it" ??? Just right click the page in browser and select "show source"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proudly announcing the FIX

After I used firebug I discovered this and if I change height:auto to height with an absolute value like 300px everything works as it should

```
.row .col img {
  height:auto;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  max-width:100%;
  width:auto;
```

FIX-for global CSS

```
.row .col img {
  height:300PX;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  max-width:100%;
  width:auto;
```

Thx for the upvotes and alos the anonymous downvotes. Also your comments really helped me to point me in the right direction...just had to look in my HTML/CSS